# Visual Studio 2019 - COM Exception: Member not found 0x80020003

Tags: c#, .net, com, visual-studio-2019

I'm using an Interop library as reference in Visual Studio 2019 which is able to execute the following code without any error:

```
using someInterop;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var flexApp = new NSF.Application();
    var proxyScan = flexApp.Scan;

    proxyScan.StartPrescan();
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    while (proxyScan.IsScanningPrescan());
}
```

But, when I declare a class and define properties to represent variable (to make them global):

```
public class NSFApp
{
    public Application someApp { get; set; }
    public ProxyScan someScan { get; set; }

    public NSFApp()
    {
        someApp = new NSF.Application();
        someScan = someApp.Scan;
    }
}
```

and then use it in the application, it throws a COM Exception -  Member not found 0x80020003

```
private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var nsf = new NSFApp();

    if (chkSimulation.Checked) { nsf.someApp.Simulation = true; }

    nsf.someScan.StartPrescan();
    
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    while (nsf.someScan.IsScanningPrescan());
}
```

Error details:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  HResult=0x80020003
  Message=Member not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
   at Nanosurf_C3000.IProxyScan.IsScanningPrescan()
   at _AFMTestStub.Form1.btnConnect_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Form1.cs:line 83
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at _AFMTestStub.Program.Main() in C:\Program.cs:line 19
```

Unable to decipher the cause!

Comment: You have a link to this NSF?

Comment: What do you mean by 'Link'?

Comment: We cannot help debug your NSF thing if we don't know what this is. Link to a project page?

Comment: For grins, in your first example, what is the type of flexApp? You declare it as "var" and not "Application". Set a breakpoint in the first function after it is assigned and look at the type. You might try making the variables in the class dynamic if nothing else works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the variable to Dynamic did the magic.

Thank you Joseph! –

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer.